# How to have restriction in comparing textbox value?

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub txtuser_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtuser.LostFocus
    Try
        con.Open()
        adapter.Fill(table)
        sql = "Select * from login "
        command = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
        myreader = command.ExecuteReader

        Dim a As Integer
        Dim b As Integer
        a = table.Rows.Count
        a -= 1
        b = 0

        If table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            While (b <= a)
                If txtuser.Text = table.Rows(b).Item("username") Then

                    usercons.Visible = True
                    PictureBox1.Visible = False
                    txtuser.Text = ""
                    btnsave.Enabled = False

                ElseIf Not txtuser.Text = table.Rows(b).Item("username") Then

                    usercons.Visible = False
                    PictureBox1.Visible = True
                    btnsave.Enabled = False

                End If

                b += 1

            End While
        End If

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox("An Error Occurred. " & ex.Number & " – " & ex.Message)
    End Try
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the quick but highly dangerous way of doing it open to all sorts of abuse:

```
sql = "Select * from login WHERE username='" & txtuser.Text & "'
```

There is a better way, create a parameter:

```
con.Open()
adapter.Fill(table)
sql = "Select * from login WHERE username=@username"
command = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
Dim param As New SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar)
command.Parameters.Add(param)
myreader = command.ExecuteReader
```

Then check the Rows property, if more than 0 rows, you have selected the user.